# Insert several same objects in the same stackview

Tags: ios, swift, subview, uistackview

I would like to insert in the same stackview, four objects (stackview1, stackview2, stackview3, stackview3) that are given by the same function `setupIngredientStackView()`. But when I run my code, the simulator displays just one object. The others are replaced by blanks.

```
fileprivate func setupIngredientStackView() -> UIStackView {
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [ingredient, quantité, prix])
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.axis = .horizontal
    return stackView
}

fileprivate func setupPageStackView(){
    let stackview1 = setupIngredientStackView()
    let stackview2 = setupIngredientStackView()
    let stackview3 = setupIngredientStackView()
    let stackview4 = setupIngredientStackView()
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [NomDuPlat,titleIgrendient,stackview1 ,stackview2 ,stackview3 ,stackview4 , etiquettePrixTotal,date,nombreDePersonne])

    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 80).isActive = true
    stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    stackView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the contents of the child stack-views. UIViews are reference objects, so if you pass your array `[ingredient, quantité, prix]` to multiple stack views, you are passing the same view objects each time, which doesn't work. Only one of those stack views will have contents; the rest will be empty.

You can't use the same view object in multiple places on the screen at the same time. You need to change your `setupIngredientStackView()` function to create new ingredients objects for each stack view that it creates.